# How to escape '@' char in JFace menu labels

Tags: menu, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

We are using the JFace menu manager. Some of our menu items contain `@` chars. For example, if we are displaying emails as a list of menu items.

When we do that, the menu doesn't show the `@` char as is but introduces a space as shown below.

The code to create the menu entries is as follows:

```
IMenuManager mgr = ... 
mgr.add( new Action( "dataloader.dev@datasert.com" ) { 
  @Override 
  public void run() { 
    // Action run 
  } 
} );
```

My question is, how do we escape the `@` char?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, special characters can be escaped them through duplication. In this case, however, there seems to be a bug (or feature?) in JFace preventing this.

As suggested in the comments, the only workaround seems to be to append an `@` character at the end of the menu label. With this trick applied, the menu label shows correctly. Only some extra space is added to the right of the label.

Comment: When I double `@` them, SWT shows first `@` char but adds space after that. For ex., when I specify `foo@@bar.org` it shows as `foo@   bar.org`

Comment: Another interesting find. For the items, which have `@`, I just suffixed another `@`. Now menu items are shown as is (may be with space at the end which user cannot see). So if there is single `@`, it shows then as spaces. If there are two `@`s, it shows first `@` as is and converts second one to spaces.

Comment: You seem to be using macOS, could you post the code you use to create the menu item?

Comment: This is what I do.


    IMenuManager mgr = ... //Get menu manager 
            mgr.add(new Action("Menu Label") {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Action run
                }
            });

Comment: Where is the `@` character? In the 'Menu Label'? Please edit the original post and add the code so that it remains readable.

Comment: Added the actual labels.